# pyplot step function does not draw a level for first/last point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am attempting to create a step plot that has a horizontal step or level for each point in the input data. Regardless of whether you specify "pre" or "post" for the where argument, `pyplot.step` will not do this. If you specify "pre", it will draw a vertical line from the first point, but no step for that value. If you specify "post", the opposite occurs. See code below for a demo of this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Series to plot
years = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
data = [125, 78, 113, 56, 98, 140]

#Plot series
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax.step(years, data, where='post')
plt.show()
```

Output of above

[image]

For context, the application is a time series plot that shows a horizontal level for the time period corresponding to each y value. I have a data set where each point represents a summary statistic for a year, so each y value applies to an entire year, not a single point in time. Therefore, the step plot seems an intuitive way to show this. I realize a bar graph or histogram might provide more control regarding my issue, but, since I have continuous data series, a line plot is preferable.

Is there a way to alter this behavior so that a horizontal line is drawn for all of the points, including BOTH the first and last points?

Comment: It is doing exactly what the documentation describes.

Comment: What exactly is the desired output and what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pyplot.stairs` as an alternative gives the desired results. You may need to do a small transformation to take you from x-centers to x-edges.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
years = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
data = [125, 78, 113, 56, 98, 140]

# convert from mid points to edges 
width = 1 # one year steps
year_edges = []
for year in years:
    year_edges.append(year + width/2)
year_edges.insert(0,year_edges[0] - width)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax.stairs(data, year_edges,lw=1)

plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]

I appreciate this is a very late answer but found this thread when having a similar issue when trying to draw a step plot with the counts/bin-centers of a previously produced histogram.

Searching online brought me here, and I subsequently found a solution that I hope can help others.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that pyplot does not know where your "next" x value is, ie. doesn't know up to which point to extend the horizontal line.
So you need to manually add another x value to the end (post) or beginning (pre), and copy the last/first y value.

Comment: This is the work-around I ultimately used. I was hoping there was a way to tell `pyplot` to do this without modifying the input data.